# MySQL - Integration of Java and MySQL Procedures and Functions Issue

Tags: java, mysql, sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

```
CallableStatement callStmt = conn.prepareCall("{ ? = call get_test(?) }");
callStmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.OTHER);
callStmt.setObject(2, testParam);
callStmt.execute();
```

PostgreSQL
The above code shows how to call a stored procedure from PostgreSQL database which is currently implemented on the application I'm working with.

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```
CallableStatement callStmt = conn.prepareCall("{ call get_test(?) }");
callStmt.setObject(1, testParam);
callStmt.execute();
```

MySQL
Using the same logic from the code implementing PostgreSQL database, above is the code I tried when implementing MySQL on my application. However, the procedure I'm calling is treated as a function. This will result to an error that says `get_test` function is not existing.
On the other hand, the code below works perfectly fine.

```
PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareCall("{ call get_test(?) }");
prepStmt .setObject(1, testParam);
prepStmt .execute();
```

Here's my question:
- Why does Java treats the stored procedure as Function when using CallableStatement?

Comment: Try to put a space after the function name and before the opening parenthesis, MySQL is rather picky with this sometimes: `conn.prepareCall("{ call get_test (?) }")`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it makes big distinction between procedures and functions at all. 
Just use prepareCall(), not prepareStatement() to call sql function or procedure and everything will work perfectly.

By the way, your PostgreSQL example uses prepareCall as well.

And I presume this line 
    CallableStatement callStmt = conn.prepareStatement("{ call get_test(?) }");
would not even compile.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. Sorry for not paying attention to codes.